# php / perl Experimenting with syntax "9"?

Tags: php, perl, str-replace

I'm currently just toying with PHP and it's syntax. But I am getting an random result.

My idea is to use perl to generate HTML and then replace certian keywords with PHP define. However playing with this, this is my idea for now

dino.php

```
<?php
 $lol = "Seriously, so I can enter text here from DB and stuff...";
function callback($buffer,$lol)

{
  return (str_replace("MSG", "$lol", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

$html = shell_exec("/usr/bin/perl /fox/perl/simple.pl 2>&1");
print ($html);

$css = shell_exec("/usr/bin/perl /fox/perl/css.pl 2>&1");
print ($css);  


ob_end_flush();
?>
```

simple.pl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
print <<HTML;
<table width="auto" border="1" class="center" id="container" cellspacing="10">
<td id="main_content" width="auto" ><b>Baa! </b><br />
    Well? what you doing here.. Baaa <br />
     MSG
<br />

</td>

<br />
</table>
HTML
```

Now, the page renders perfectly, however where the string **MSG** exists, I get a result of **9**

```
Baa!
Well? what you doing here.. Baaa
9
```

Curious to what's causing nine to appear, I'm assuming i'm counting some sort of value but not sure what value and if I am, why **9**? Is there another syntax I should be using to do such?

If I remove the declaration with a string ("MSG", "lol", $buffer) it behaves as it should. Replacing MSG with lol.

thxs.

Comment: The `$lol` parameter passed to your callback by PHP's ob functions is not what you think it is.  It's a bitmask, not the string you defined above.  That's why you're seeing 9, as 9 is the combination of the flags passed to the function.

Comment: I'm sorry, but ewww; that's such a bad representation of Perl I shuddered. That's not quite how we do things ;)

Comment: @drew010 - thanks, stevieb lol, I feel dirty enough just replacing "EOF" with "HTML",  what could I do better?

Comment: it's definitely valid, that's for sure. You get a pass because I can tell you're just testing things out. Out of curiosity, what's your end goal for what you're doing? Is this a conceptual test of a real world problem, or are you just playing around. I'm legitimately curious.

Comment: Kind of trying to make a site blog thing, using sqlite as the database. I've been finding PHP a bit clunky on HTML rendering and reading other replies it's tricky to do so. This is just an idea to test a shoutbox type thing. So if I can take a users post data push that in to a varible, create an pre-defined temple and then just raw output the code. ("MSG" $comment").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ob_start` is not expecting incoming variables like `$foo` .  As drew010 indicated, the format for your callback must be:

```
string handler ( string $buffer [, int $phase ] )
```

You can work around it in a couple of ways.  For example:

```
ob_start(function($buffer) use ($lol) {
  return (str_replace("MSG", "$lol", $buffer));
});
```

or if you don't mind global variables:

```
function callback($buffer)
{
  global $lol;
  return (str_replace("MSG", "$lol", $buffer));
}
ob_start("callback")
```

Comment: globals are fun, and now it just works. Black Magiic. Thanks!